# Why doesn't Loki escape while the Avengers are fighting each other?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

While Thor and Iron Man are fighting, Loki has plenty of time in which to try to escape. Why doesn't he do so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the fight between Thor and Iron Man.  Loki didn't escape *because he wanted to be caught and taken to the air ship.*. That was part of his plan.

Comment: Thor: "Loki is a prisoner."  Nick Fury: "Then why do I feel like he's the only person on this boat who wants to be here?"